# Flutter - Search bar displaying duplicate results

Tags: flutter, search

I am using search delegate to implement my search function. It can search the serial number or even the station location. Searching the serial number seems to be working fine, but when i search the location, it results in duplication of my results. The list seems to rebuild and show duplicate results Below here is the screenshot of the output when I search the location. Any help would be very appreciated.

[Search bar display duplicate results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLKKA.jpg)

```
    class Search extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final List stationList;
  Search(
    this.stationList,
  );

  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2),
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              buildResults(context);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              query = '';
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear)),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    print(stationList);
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? stationList
        : stationList
            .where((element) => element['serial_number']
                .toString()
                .toUpperCase()
                .startsWith(query.toUpperCase()) 
                || element['location']
                .toString()
                .toUpperCase()
                .startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
            .toList();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 246, 247),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: suggestionList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: ListView(
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          for (int index = 0;
                              index < suggestionList.length;
                              index++)
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => StationData(
                                              stationSerialNumber:
                                                  suggestionList[index]
                                                      ['serial_number'],
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 1),
                                color: ColorTheme.white,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 1,
                                        child: LayoutBuilder(
                                          builder: (context, constraints) {
                                            return Container(
                                              child: Column(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceEvenly,
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    child:
                                                        SingleChildScrollView(
                                                      scrollDirection:
                                                          Axis.horizontal,
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Icon(
                                                            Icons.wifi_tethering,
                                                            color: ColorTheme.secondary,
                                                            size: constraints.maxWidth *10 /100,
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(
                                                              width: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *1.5),
                                                          Column(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Row(
                                                                children: [
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                    width: constraints.maxWidth *0.02,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    '${suggestionList[index]['serial_number']}',
                                                                    style:
                                                                        TextStyle(
                                                                      fontSize:ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *2.5,
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                    width: constraints.maxWidth *0.05,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  TextButton(
                                                                    onPressed:null,
                                                                    child: Text(
                                                                      '${suggestionList[index]['status']}',
                                                                      style:
                                                                          TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:
                                                                            ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *1.8,
                                                                        color: suggestionList[index]['status'] =='Under QC'
                                                                            ? Colors.redAccent
                                                                            : Colors.greenAccent,
                                                                        fontWeight:
                                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                                      ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                  height: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *1),
                                                              Row(
                                                                children: [
                                                                  Icon(
                                                                    Icons.location_on,
                                                                    color: ColorTheme.secondary,
                                                                    size: constraints.maxWidth *4 /100,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *1 / 100),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    '${suggestionList[index]['location']}',
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *2,
                                                                        color: ColorTheme.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *5 /100),
                                                                  Icon(
                                                                    Icons.access_time,
                                                                    color: ColorTheme.secondary,
                                                                    size: constraints.maxWidth * 4 /100,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *1 /100),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    'Created at ${suggestionList[index]['date_added'].split(' ')[0]}',
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *2,
                                                                        color: ColorTheme.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *10 /100),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                          child: Row(children: [
                                            IconButton(onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.push(context,
                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                        builder: (context) =>StationData(
                                                              stationSerialNumber:suggestionList[index]['serial_number'],
                                                            )));
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.navigate_next,
                                                color: ColorTheme.grey,
                                                size: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *6,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ]))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ],
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? stationList
        : stationList
            .where((element) => element['serial_number']
                .toString()
                .toUpperCase()
                .startsWith(query.toUpperCase()) 
                || element['location']
                .toString()
                .toUpperCase()
                .startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
            .toList();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 246, 247),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: suggestionList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: ListView(
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          for (int index = 0;
                              index < suggestionList.length;
                              index++)
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => StationData(
                                              stationSerialNumber:suggestionList[index]['serial_number'],
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical * 1),
                                color: ColorTheme.white,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 1,
                                        child: LayoutBuilder(
                                          builder: (context, constraints) {
                                            return Container(
                                              child: Column(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    child:SingleChildScrollView(
                                                      scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Icon(
                                                            Icons.wifi_tethering,
                                                            color: ColorTheme.secondary,
                                                            size: constraints.maxWidth *10 /100,
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(
                                                              width: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *1.5),
                                                          Column(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Row(
                                                                children: [
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                    width: constraints.maxWidth *0.02,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    '${suggestionList[index]['serial_number']}',
                                                                    style:TextStyle(
                                                                      fontSize:ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *2.5,
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                    width: constraints.maxWidth *0.05,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  TextButton(
                                                                    onPressed:null,
                                                                    child: Text(
                                                                      '${suggestionList[index]['status']}',
                                                                      style:TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *1.8,
                                                                        color: suggestionList[index]['status'] =='Under QC'
                                                                            ? Colors.redAccent
                                                                            : Colors.greenAccent,
                                                                        fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,
                                                                      ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                  height: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *1),
                                                              Row(
                                                                children: [
                                                                  Icon(
                                                                    Icons.location_on,
                                                                    color: ColorTheme.secondary,
                                                                    size: constraints.maxWidth *4 /100,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *1 /100),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    '${suggestionList[index]['location']}',
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *2,
                                                                        color: ColorTheme.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *5 /100),
                                                                  Icon(
                                                                    Icons.access_time,
                                                                    color: ColorTheme.secondary,
                                                                    size: constraints.maxWidth *4 /100,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *1 /100),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    'Created at ${suggestionList[index]['date_added'].split(' ')[0]}',
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontSize:
                                                                            ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *2,
                                                                        color: ColorTheme.black),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                      width: constraints.maxWidth *10 /100),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                          child: Row(children: [
                                            IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.push(
                                                    context,
                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                        builder: (context) =>
                                                            StationData(
                                                              stationSerialNumber:
                                                                  suggestionList[index]['serial_number'],
                                                            )));
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.navigate_next,
                                                color: ColorTheme.grey,
                                                size: ScreenSize.blockSizeVertical *6,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ]))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ],
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toSet()` . If the iterable contains an element more than once it gets deleted... so you get a clean list.

Comment: https://docs.w3cub.com/dart~2/dart-svg/attributeclassset/toset